# Docker - mounted directory is empty inside container

Tags: docker, volume

I am attempting to mount a non-empty directory into a container, however, the directory inside the container is empty. The directory does *not* already exist in the container. My command is:

`docker run --volume /tmp:/test busybox:latest ls -l /test`

I have also tried this using the `--mount` flag instead but no success. Why is the `/test` directory inside my container empty? It should contain the contents of `/tmp` from the host.

Comment: How are you running docker? Can you show an example with the ls command on the host vs inside the container.

Comment: Do you see some files or directories when you run `ls -l /tmp`? Please add the output of this command to your question by editing it.

Comment: @Boon, where is your `tmp` directory is located? are you referring to `tmp` in the root location of the os file system or is it a directory you created?

Comment: This command will work if you created the directory => `docker run --volume "$(pwd)/tmp":/test busybox:latest ls -l /test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured things out, in part provoked by @BMitch's comment. I was running Docker in a multi-node environment so Docker was creating the new container on a separate node. I solved the problem by coping the file into the new container via docker cp